# Override jquery mobile styling

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a form in my html document that contains a submit button like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

No matter what I try, I am not able to override the Jquery Mobile styling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What specific thing are you trying to override? You need to be more precise then this. Give us some HTML and tell us what do you want to do with it.

Comment: I want to change its colour, size and alignment. I tried using style="background:#006699; position:absolute; width:200px; " but it didn't work. I'm having this problem only on elements with type "input".

Comment: Did you try with `!important`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you change anything in jQuery Mobile you need to understand one thing. HTML you have written will not be there when page is shown.

jQuery Mobile enhances page markup with additional HTML/CSS structures. If this button is used:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

its final HTML is going to look like this:

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-disabled="false" class="ui-submit ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">submit</span>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false"/>
</div>
```

So when changing jQuery Mobile elements CSS you need to change final result, not initial HTML. CSS styles applied to original element will not be copied to a new element.

Working **jsFiddle** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/6dWkV/

One last thing, when changing jQuery Mobile styles don't forget to use **`!important`** to override original styles.

**Final CSS:**

```
.ui-submit {
    position: relative !important;
    float: right !important;
    background: red !important;
    height: 300px !important;
    width: 300px !important;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) I didn't know that. The overriding still isn't working though

Comment: Take a look at my example, it works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/6dWkV/

Comment: I tried yours out on jsFiddle and it works like a charm. The moment I include it in mine, it doesn't. Does it change anything if my input button is within a form?
Like this:

<div data-role="content">
<form>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>

I've just left out the other components of the form for the sake of compactness.

Comment: First tell me this, do you use 1 HTML with several pages or do you use several HTML files?

Comment: I use multiple files. One per page plus my css file.

Comment: Excellent now tell me does every page has its own CSS file or do you call everything inside a first HTML file?

Comment: I have just one CSS file as of now.

My styling on divs and anchors works just fine. Just a problem with elements of type 'input'.

Comment: I have another input of type 'text' and it isn't letting me change the width

Comment: This is because my example will work only on submit buttons. Every different jQuery Mobile widget has its own structures. Tell me what browser are you using and have you heard of firebug plugin for firefox and chrome? It can be used to inspect page HTML/CSS structure. You can use it to find out what input type="text" structure looks like.